# How to convert CSV columns into Vowpal Wabbit txt input file

Tags: python, vowpalwabbit

I am trying to convert csv (with 10 columns) to vowpal wabbit input format txt file. Some csv columns has integer values and some have strings (like: com.12346.xyz). For example if my csv columns look like this:

```
loss       weight         SSD_id      weight    label      imp            feat_val
0.693147   0.693147            1         1.0  -1.0000   0.0000       com.12346.xyz
0.419189   0.145231            2         2.0   1.0000  -1.8559       com.12346.xyz
0.235457   0.051725            4         4.0  -1.0000  -2.7588       com.12356.xyz
6.371911   12.508365           8         8.0  -1.0000  -3.7784       com.12346.xyz
3.485084   0.598258           16        16.0   1.0000  -2.2767       com.12346.xyz
1.765249   0.045413           32        32.0  -1.0000  -2.8924       com.1236.xyz
1.017911   0.270573           64        64.0  -1.0000  -3.0438       com.12236.xyz
0.611419   0.204927          128       128.0   1.0000  -3.1539       com.16746.xyz
0.469127   0.326834          256       256.0  -1.0000  -1.6101       com.1946.xyz
0.403473   0.337820          512       512.0   1.0000  -2.8843       com.126.xyz
0.337348   0.271222         1024      1024.0  -1.0000  -2.5209       com.1346.xyz
0.328909   0.320471         2048      2048.0   1.0000  -2.0732       com.1234.xyz
0.309401   0.289892         4096      4096.0   1.0000  -2.7639       com.12396.xyz
```

and vowpal wabbit input format looks like this:

```
label weight |i imp SSD_id loss |c feat_val
```

and inside vowpal wabbit txt file values should be:

```
-1 0.051725 |i imp:-2.7588 SSD_id:4 loss:0.235457 |c feat_val=com.12356.xyz
 1 0.598258 |i imp:-2.7588 SSD_id:4 loss:3.485034 |c feat_val=com.12346.xyz
```

... and so on... for all the rows values. I have huge number of rows in the csv file that I want to convert to the above format and save all of them in single txt file. I have started with this small function given below:

```
def to_new_format(document, label=None):
      return str(label or '') + ' |i ' + ' '.join(re.findall('\w{3,}', document.lower())) + '\n'
to_new_format(str(text_train[1])
```

but I am completely lost now after many trials with dataframe, csv formatting and trying functions. Can someone give some direction to me how I can achieve this in minimal lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simpler to do than it might seem, because of some handy ways Pandas lets you treat sequences almost the same as you would single values in Python.

First we'll import your CSV file, treating all values as strings to make our formatting easier:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test_data.txt', dtype=pd.StringDtype())
```

Your `label` column is recorded like `1.0000` in your file, but you don't want the decimal or zeroes in your output. We can fix that using Pandas' [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings) method.

```py
df.label = df.label.str.replace('.0000', '', regex=False)
```

And here's the magical part: we can concatenate these just like if they were individual strings!

```py
formatted = (
    df.label + ' ' + df.weight +
    ' |i imp:' + df.imp +
    ' SSD_id: ' + df.SSD_id +
    ' loss:' + df.loss +
    ' |c feat_val=' + df.feat_val +
    '\n'
)
```

That code *looks* would it would create a string, but because of how it includes the dataframe's columns (each of which is a Pandas sequence), the result is a sequence too:

```py
print(formatted)

0     -1 0.693147 |i imp:0.0000 SSD_id: 1 loss:0.693...
1     1 0.145231 |i imp:-1.8559 SSD_id: 2 loss:0.419...
2     -1 0.051725 |i imp:-2.7588 SSD_id: 4 loss:0.23...
3     -1 12.508365 |i imp:-3.7784 SSD_id: 8 loss:6.3...
4     1 0.598258 |i imp:-2.2767 SSD_id: 16 loss:3.48...
5     -1 0.045413 |i imp:-2.8924 SSD_id: 32 loss:1.7...
6     -1 0.270573 |i imp:-3.0438 SSD_id: 64 loss:1.0...
7     1 0.204927 |i imp:-3.1539 SSD_id: 128 loss:0.6...
8     -1 0.326834 |i imp:-1.6101 SSD_id: 256 loss:0....
9     1 0.337820 |i imp:-2.8843 SSD_id: 512 loss:0.4...
10    -1 0.271222 |i imp:-2.5209 SSD_id: 1024 loss:0...
11    1 0.320471 |i imp:-2.0732 SSD_id: 2048 loss:0....
12    1 0.289892 |i imp:-2.7639 SSD_id: 4096 loss:0....
```

Each line is truncated when printed like this, but it's all in there. For instance:

```py
print(formatted[0])

-1 0.693147 |i imp:0.0000 SSD_id: 1 loss:0.693147 |c feat_val=com.12346.xyz
```

All that's left is to save it to a file:

```py
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(formatted)
```

Comment: your solution is very clean and outstanding and easy to understand. I have learned something new. I have been trying this since one week. Yes you are right it looks complex but simple to implement if done in right way. If the data is coming in json format, would this be still valid?

Comment: Glad it helps! To be honest I'm learning Pandas now too, and answering this question was educational for me. It just so happens that Pandas has a [`read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) method too! You might have to tweak things, depending on how exactly your file is formatted, but yes, this approach should still work.

Comment: I will try with read_json and will post here if it worked. The data is basically coming in json format when request is sent but it was too complex for me to have some solution around that so thought to try with csv first. Yes, your solution approach is perfectly working what I was trying to do with csv and will now try with json.

Answer (score 2):

In recent releases Vowpal Wabbit has a Python module that eases the conversion of pandas `DataFrame` to Vowpal Wabbit input format.

For example using **version 8.11.0** and assuming that your column types are the following :

```
loss        float64
weight      float64
SSD_id        int64
weight.1    float64
label         int64
imp         float64
feat_val     object
dtype: object
```

you could use the following code

```py
from vowpalwabbit.DFtoVW import DFtoVW, SimpleLabel, Namespace, Feature

label = SimpleLabel(label="label", weight="weight")
namespaces = [
    Namespace(features=[Feature(col) for col in ["imp", "SSD_id", "loss"]], name="i"),
    Namespace(features=Feature("feat_val"), name="c")
]

converter = DFtoVW(df=dat, label=label, namespaces=namespaces)
```

then call the method `convert_df` to get the output

```
examples = converter.convert_df()

print(examples)

['-1 0.693147 |i imp:0.0 SSD_id:1 loss:0.693147 |c feat_val=com.12346.xyz',
 '1 0.145231 |i imp:-1.8559 SSD_id:2 loss:0.419189 |c feat_val=com.12346.xyz',
 '-1 0.051725 |i imp:-2.7588 SSD_id:4 loss:0.235457 |c feat_val=com.12356.xyz',
 '-1 12.508365 |i imp:-3.7784 SSD_id:8 loss:6.371911 |c feat_val=com.12346.xyz',
 '1 0.598258 |i imp:-2.2767 SSD_id:16 loss:3.485084 |c feat_val=com.12346.xyz',
 '-1 0.045413 |i imp:-2.8924 SSD_id:32 loss:1.765249 |c feat_val=com.1236.xyz',
 '-1 0.270573 |i imp:-3.0438 SSD_id:64 loss:1.017911 |c feat_val=com.12236.xyz',
 '1 0.204927 |i imp:-3.1539 SSD_id:128 loss:0.611419 |c feat_val=com.16746.xyz',
 '-1 0.326834 |i imp:-1.6101 SSD_id:256 loss:0.469127 |c feat_val=com.1946.xyz',
 '1 0.33782 |i imp:-2.8843 SSD_id:512 loss:0.403473 |c feat_val=com.126.xyz',
 '-1 0.271222 |i imp:-2.5209 SSD_id:1024 loss:0.337348 |c feat_val=com.1346.xyz',
 '1 0.320471 |i imp:-2.0732 SSD_id:2048 loss:0.328909 |c feat_val=com.1234.xyz',
 '1 0.289892 |i imp:-2.7639 SSD_id:4096 loss:0.309401 |c feat_val=com.12396.xyz']
```

and write it to file

```
with open("test.dat", "w") as f:
    for example in examples:
        f.writelines(example+"\n")
```